# how to pass data from compile to linking function in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I do some calculations based on DOM elements in the compile function of a directive. I need to store the result in the scope, so I was trying to pass this data to the linking function (which has access to the scope), but I don't know how to do it.

I need to perform these calculations in the compile function since I need to access DOM elements before they are processed by the linking function of other directives (using directive priority).

Comment: I've succeded using jQuery.data() but I feel this is not "the angular way"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's enough considering the scope of JavaScript symbols.  See this http://jsfiddle.net/JV7vH/1/

you define a compile function that has to return a link function. because it's an inner function, symbols from parent functions are visible.

```js
app.directive('ui',function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    template: '<div class="mcb">hey</div>',
    compile: function ($tElement, $tAttrs) {
        var foo = "a valuable value";
        console.log('compiling' + foo);
        return function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log('linking:' + foo);
        }
    }  
  }
});
```

you might also want to read about the [order of execution of compile-link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/bBgJ6Tb-mHo/PDSU76pNPtAJ)
@joshdavidmiller said that given:

```
<div directive1>
  <div directive2>
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

the order of execution is

```
directive1: compile
  directive2: compile
directive1: controller
directive1: pre-link
  directive2: controller
  directive2: pre-link
  directive2: post-link
directive1: post-link
```

Comment: thank you. I've tried to replicate the fiddle, but having two directives that should produce different output, if I do console.log(foo) in the linking function it outputs the last value twice, while in the compile function of course works fine... The weird thing is that a similar directive works in your fiddle.

Comment: do you call $compile(element)(scope) at any point? what's more, if you have nested directives it'll call first all the compile fn, then the links (your link fn is strictly a post-link function)

Comment: I was missing **var** foo!